# i'm not so good at maths

Tags: functions

I'm facing a problem where lets say, 
I'm buying this item A for 5 dollares, i do some work on it and i obtain 5 different items 1B which is worth 2 dollars, 2 items C which are worth 3 dollars each, 1 items D which is worth 5 dollars and 1 items E which is worth 1 dollars. That is 14 dollars total, about 2.8 dollars per item.
Now i want to lower prices, accordingly, i want to make it an avearage of 2.5 dollars per item, which will be 12.5 total. Is there any formula that allows me to reduce automatically the prices? I want the items that cost the most to have a higher % of price reduction. thanks in advance

**1A (5) = 1B(2) + 2C(2x3) + 1D(5) + 1E(1)**

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "I work this item?"  What pricing are you trying to control?  What parts of the data are fixed and which are variable.  I'm voting to close this question because it's unclear.  If you edit it to be understandable, I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: Thanks mr Saulspatz. What i meant was that i'm buying  one item A for 5 dollares, i do some work on it and i obtain 5 diferent items, B, 2xC, 1D and 1E, which in the end i will sell for 14 dollares, their cost is diferent. but the avearage i get is about 2.8 dollars per item. Now i want to lower costs, accordingly, because items have pricing diferences. Now lets say i want to make the avearage cost of 2.5 dollares per item, how do i price them accordingly?

Comment: First, you should edit the question body to make things clearer.  Lots of people browsing the questions will vote to close without reading the comments.  Second, if you want to sell $5$ items at an average cost of $2.50$ each, the total price has to be $12.50.$  Obviously, there are a lot of ways to choose the prices.  Unless you tell us more about the desired solution, I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: i think i got it now Mr, sorry once again...

Comment: OK, now I think I understand what you're trying to do.  There still is not a single solution, but I know enough to answer the question.  I'll write an answer in a little while.

Comment: "i'm not so good at maths" is not a good title for a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single solution to this question.  You want to apportion a total price reduction of $\$2.50$ among the various items, with a higher percentage price reduction among the higher-price items.  Since $${12.5\over 14}\approx.89,$$ we want a total reduction of about $11\%.$  If we were to make the same percentage reduction to all the prices, we'd apply the $11\%$ reduction to all prices, but as it is, we'll apply a reduction of more than $11\%$ to the more expensive items, and a reduction of less than $11\%$ to the cheaper ones.

For example, you might reduce the price of the $\$5$ item by $13\%$ ($65$ cents), the price of the two $\$3$ items by $11\%$ ($66$ cents), the price of the $
\$2$ item by $7\%$ ($14$ cents) and the price of the $\$1$ dollar item by $5\%$ ($5$ cents).  This give a total reduction of $\$1.50,$ as desired.

As you can see, there are lots of ways of doing it.  Only you can decide what's best.

Comment: Thanks a lot Saulspatz,  that's what i wanted but let me ask you something, how did you manage to get the different %s and be able to reach the $1.50 reduction. What was the calculation behind it? Thank you so much mr!

Comment: I just made them up.  At the end, you know what the reduction in the last item hast to be to make the total come out to be $\$1.50.$